# How do I check values of variables from an included makefile?

Tags: makefile

#### ../Makefile

```
BAR=sometext
```

#### Makefile

```
include ../Makefile

FOO=othertext

ifneq ($(BAR),)
FOOBAR=$(FOO) $(BAR)
else
FOOBAR=$(FOO)
endif

all:
        @echo $(FOOBAR)
```

This will print `"othertext"` regardless of whether I have `BAR` defined in `../Makefile`. Why is that? If i have `BAR` defined locally, it will print `"othertext sometext"` which is what I want. But I'm stuck using an include in my situation.

I've tried various scenarios using `$(value $(BAR))` `$(strip $(BAR))`, etc but I can't seem to get this to work how I want.

Comment: Did you check that your `include ../Makefile` really works? As far as I recall, `make` will gloss over non-existant `include ` targets. Put a `$(info I am here!)` in the included file to see if or if not.

Comment: 1. If it was working as you expect you would get `othertext bar`, not `othertext sometext`. Or is it a typo in your question?
2. Just tested with GNU make 4,2,1 and it does print `othertext bar`. Which make do you use? 3. I suspect that your real problem is related to the difference between simply expanded variables and recursively expanded variables. You could maybe look at this in the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet You are right, I edited the question to mean what I meant.
Oddly enough, I just tried it today as I put it above, and it works outside of the environment I was testing in. I'll double back to see if my include was wrong. Maybe I was just tired :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this other way around. In `Makefile`:

```
FOO=othertext
BAR=$(FOO)

include ../Makefile

all:
    @echo $(BAR)
```

and `../Makefile`

```
BAR+=sometext
```